# Grid Layout view Java Swing component position

Tags: java, swing, layout, grid

I have problem using Grid Layout in Java Swing. I create Panel and add `GridLayout` with 4 columns and 2 rows.

I try to add `JButton` inside it, but the `JButton` stretch the width.
Look this image :

[image]

I want create `JButton` position like this, because I want to make image gallery using Java Swing. 
Look this image :

[image]

Any idea? Thanks before :)

Comment: *"Any idea?"*  After looking at the first image, my advice would be to crop the image to the problem part and save it as PNG.  If it had been small enough I would have edited it into the question, but at 279KB, it is too large.  Also, for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Use GridBagLayout and specify GridBagConstraints. It will help you to render components as you want

Kindly refer [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the layout http://java-sl.com/tip_columns_flow_layout.html

It's kind of Win Explorer layout when components flow to fill columns to available width.

Comment: How i can implement it in Netbeans?<br/>
I have use this step in Netbeans :

 1. Create JFrameForm 
 2. Create ColumnsFlowLayout class and implements LayoutManager
 3. Create JPanel and Customize Code become :<br/>
    `Jpanel jPanel1 = new JPanel(new ColumnsFlowLayout(3,3));`

When i run , my Frame not show anything inside it. But when i not use Netbeans Designer (i mean i create JPanel manually) i have it works perfectly.<br/>
Please help me, Thanks